# Script having trouble passing Unicode through a REST interface

Tags: python, rest, unicode

I am having trouble getting my Python script to ass Unicode data over RESTful http call.

I have a script that reads data from web site X using a REST interface and then pushes it into web site Y using it's REST interface.  Both system are open source and are run on our servers.  Site X uses PHP, Apache and PostgreSQL.  Site Y is Java, Tomcat and PostgreSQL.  The script doing the processing is currently in Python.

In general, the script works very well.  We do have a few international users, and when trying to process a user with unicode characters in their name things break down.  The original version of the script read the JSON data into the Python.  The data was converted automagically into Unicode.  I am pretty sure everything was working fine up to this point.  To output the data I used subprocess.Popen() to call curl.  This works for regular ascii, but the unicode was getting mangled somewhere in transit.  I didn't get an error anywhere, but when viewing the results on site B it is no longer correctly encoded.

I know that Unicode is supported for these fields because I can craft a request using Firefox that correctly adds the data to site B.

Next idea was to not use curl, but just do everything in Python.  I experimented by passing a hand constructed Unicode string to Python's urllib to make the REST call, but I received an error from urllib.urlopen(): 
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 103-105: ordinal not in range(128)`

Any ideas on how to make this work?  I would rather not re-write too much, but if there is another scripting language that would be better suited I wouldn't mind hearing about that also.

Here is my Python test script:

```
import urllib

uni = u"abc_\u03a0\u03a3\u03a9"

post = u"xdat%3Auser.login=unitest&"
post += u"xdat%3Auser.primary_password=nauihe4r93nf83jshhd83&"
post += u"xdat%3Auser.firstname=" + uni + "&"
post += u"xdat%3Auser.lastname=" + uni ;

url = u"http://localhost:8081/xnat/app/action/XDATRegisterUser"

data = urllib.urlopen(url,post).read()
```

Comment: Duplicate of so very many posts -- look at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UnicodeEncodeError and pick your favorite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Unicode UnicodeEncodeError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077564/python-unicode-unicodeencodeerror)

Answer (score 2):

With regard to your test script, it is failing because you are passing unicode object to `urllib.urlencode()` (it is being called for you by `urlopen()`). It does not support unicode objects, so it implicitly encodes using the default charset, which is `ascii`. Obviously, it fails.

The simplest way to handle POSTing unicode objects is to be explicit; Gather your data and build a dict, encode unicode values with an appropriate charset, urlencode the dict (to get a POSTable ascii string), then initiate the request. Your example could be rewritten as:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

## Build our post data dict
data = {
    'xdat:user.login' : u'unitest', 
    'xdat:primary_password' : u'nauihe4r93nf83jshhd83', 
    'xdat:firstname' : u"abc_\u03a0\u03a3\u03a9", 
    'xdat:lastname' : u"abc_\u03a0\u03a3\u03a9", 
}

## Encode the unicode using an appropriate charset
data = dict([(key, value.encode('utf8')) for key, value in data.iteritems()])

## Urlencode it for POSTing
data = urllib.urlencode(data)

## Build a POST request, get the response
url = "http://localhost:8081/xnat/app/action/XDATRegisterUser"
request = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

**EDIT:** More generally, when you make an http request with python (say `urllib2.urlopen`), 
the content of the response is *not* decoded to unicode for you. That means you need to be aware of the encoding used by the server that sent it. Look at the `content-type` header; Usually it includes a `charset=xyz`.

It is always prudent to decode your input as early as possible, and encode your output as late as possible.